# How do I eliminate the "civi Dashboard" tab

Tags: dashboard

So far, I've used civiCRM to build my database. I'm about to go public on registration for an event and I don't want registrants to see the "civi Dashboard" tab.

I have my civiCRM on Drupal and I was told the secret lies in Drupal configuration but I can't find the right switch to turn it off.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "civi dashboard tab" means? Maybe edit your post to include a screenshot. My guess is you either mean shortcuts or a navigation block.

Answer (score 2):

May be turning off 'CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard' permission for user role should help

Comment: Where do I find "access Contact Dashboard"?

Comment: I can't find the way to add an image to a comment, so let me direct you to my site: events.wyominghouse.org. I'm using Drupal's Bartik 7.x-1.0 To the left of the Home tab is Civi Dashboard tab. I would like to eliminate this for anonymous users.

Comment: You should find under drupal permissions(/admin/people/permissions) also civi dashboard is a menu item you can disable from drupal menu.